# honey over a bull ants' nest

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I can't clearly understand a sentence. Could you help me?

> Anyone touch my kids, I'm going to go honey over a bullants' nest.

What does "honey over" mean here? Is she trying to say that she would lure bull ants to the person's place or something?

Thank you in advance.
Source
Movie, Snowtown

Comment: I think the nature of the threat is clear, that they're going to get bull-ants to attack the person, presumably using honey. Its probably not an exact idiom, coming from heavily accented australian english.

Comment: @mstorkson please see my answer.  It's unlikely that the person is going to find a convenient anthill and stake him out, instead she's saying her fury and determination to cause serious harm will be *like* a nest of hungry bull ants.

Comment: The full quote, which seems to have been edited down from the comment, refers specifically to using a rat to harm someone's genitalia, so I think that this being the second animal mentioned (especially considering the bullant is native to australia where the movie is set) is meant in the same manor. Although in both cases the course of action may not be specifically meant, but meant to suggest the level of violence they mean to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a woman named Sarah Palin, who about eight years ago was running for Vice President.  At that time she famously said something similar, that when her family was threatened she wanted to act like a "mama grizzly".

> “The toughest thing has been the shots taken against the kids, against the family,” said Ms. Palin. “They’re my kids. The mama grizzly bear in me comes out, makes me want to rear up on my hind legs and say, ‘Wait a minute.’"

It's an effectively aggressive animal metaphor to suggest that she will protect her kids with everything she has.  In a similar way the person using the ant metaphor will *act* like a nest of ants with honey -- she will swarm all over the person and unrelentingly attack him.